# Safari - jquery dynamic input value

Tags: jquery, dynamic, safari

I have a problem with getting value of dynamic input. The problem occurs only in Safari. Other browsers are fine.

My dynamically loaded input looks like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control active" data-inputmask="'alias':'date'" datepicker name="products[16][start_date]" onkeyup="getItemPrice(16)" required placeholder="Start Date">
```

and then I try to get its value in function this way

```
var start_date = $('input[name="products['+id+'][start_date]"]').val();
```

Unfortunately, in Safari it always returns empty value.
What should I do in this case?
Thanks

---

Edit:

The problem regards only $.val(). Everything else works fine (hide, show, etc.)
I can set the val() but can't get it.

None of the taken actions succeeded. Is there anything wrong with Safari? There must be an option to take a value of a dynamically rendered element. I've never had such issue before. Any ideas?

### *PROBLEM SOLVED*

Incompatible plugin (inputmask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider to add metadata in the input tag, not a name that seems an array because Safari is really "delicate" in these things.
For example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control active product-item" name="products[16][start_date]" data-product-id=16 onkeyup="getItemPrice(16)" required placeholder="Start Date">
```

then use the $.attr() method

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have already tried to select those inputs by class, but still no luck :(

Comment: So you can try a cycle on each .product-item with an if with the $.each(".product-item")

Comment: Well, I just realised something! The problem regards only $.val(). When I try to hide, show, modify it in any way, it works fine.